# AngularJS ng-repeat rows/ul

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON array with various objects and I want to show these objects in the HTML using ng-repeat, but as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>object 1</li>
    <li>object 2</li>
    <li>object 3</li>
    <li>object 4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>object 5</li>
    <li>object 6</li>
    <li>object 7</li>
    <li>object 8</li>
</ul>
```

Basically I want to show only 4 items per row (ul)
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use lodash library to chunk your main json array to group of 4. Then you have two ng-repeats to display the results like you want

Comment: using css, 25% of width each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the filter [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

```
ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:4"
```

UPDATE:This should work

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in arr" ng-if="$index%4==0">
  <li ng-repeat="item in arr|limitTo:4:$index" >
    {{item}} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yvmGyG3vqMEPmR0OkMiJ?p=preview)

Comment: Not in this case. If I have 80 items in my array, for example, I want to show 20 UL with 4 LI inside each UL.

Comment: Updated with a solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this sample out, In your controller:

```
var list = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15'};

// Using lodash
var chunkedList = _.chunk(list, 4);
```

In your HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="items in chunkedList">
 <li ng-repeat="item in items">Object {{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test but give it a try:

```
<ul ng-repeat="n in getNumber(number)">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:4:n*4">object 1</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.number = Math.round(items.length/4);
scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to chunk your array to multidimensional array, and then `ng-repeat` it twice with nested structure.

If you would like to change the chunk number, you may just change it to any integers you like.

[Live demo](http://codepen.io/kavare/pen/eNmzmB) is here.

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat-start="chunk in ctrl.chunkList">
    <li ng-repeat="item in chunk">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  <hr ng-repeat-end/>
</body>
```

#### JS

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', [function() {
    var self = this;
    var listLength;
    var groupNum;
    var i;

    self.list = [
      'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 
      'item6', 'item7', 'item8'
    ];

    listLength = self.list.length;
    groupNum = (listLength % 4 === 0)? listLength / 4 : Math.ceil(listLength / 4);

    self.chunkList = [];
    for (i = 0; i < groupNum; i++) {
      self.chunkList[i] = self.list.slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4);
    }

  }]);
```

Also notice that if you there's no need for other elements in the loop, you can just remove `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` and use `ng-repeat` directly instead.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="chunk in ctrl.chunkList">
    <li ng-repeat="item in chunk">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

#### Notes

This is approach is similar to [@Shivas Jayram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4520730/shivas-jayaram)'s, but without the need for `underscore` library.

Comment: Definitely my pleasure  :)